# What is the best type of ale/lager that you can add fruit to?

Tags: fruit

I am planning to make a fruit batch for my wife and I have read on when to add the fruit and how, but is there a recipe that you should stay away from?  This my be subjective to a point, but I don't think a Bock would be a good starting point.  What wort would be recommended?

Comment: In addition to what others have already added, it very much depends on the kind of fruit you care to use, as, i.e., ripe cherries may taste good in a dry, tart beer **and** a fuller-bodied dark beer, while another fruit may fit well with one or the other (but not both), or with neither. Dried fruits, typically having higher flavor intensities, may work better with darker beers while fresh, brighter fruits might work better with just the opposite.

Comment: She really likes the Angry Orchard Apple Cider and I have bottled a pear beer from Mr. Beer as a starter.  There is a lot of good answers here to start. Maybe this will help many people making a good fruity beer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make something your wife would like start by looking at what she likes to eat. Is she into tart or sweet food?

Lets assume she likes chocolate; then look at what goes well with chocolate: oranges, cherries, vanilla... you get the point. Then get a beer that represents the chocolate (stout/porter) and add the fruit that you decided on.

Lets assume your wife likes more tart things, then the easiest answer is lambic, but a pilsner or similar beer (bready/crackers) with some lemon zest to become a lemon tart could work. A weiss with tart fruit also works well.

Otherwise, take a beer that she likes and taste the beer with different fruit.

Have fun!

Comment: So pair the beer with a fuit in the way she likes to eat her fruit.  Makes  a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not a bock...you want something that doesn't have a lot of flavor on it's own, generally (although I have added chanterelle mushrooms to a wee heavy).  Good bases for fruit beers are something like A. wheat (not hefeweizen), or a blond ale.  Things that won't conflict with the fruit.

Answer (score 1):

It is ultimately subjective, but historical tradition and commercial success does suggest there's an objective aspect, too. These are some of the things I've seen and/or experienced that work better/more accessibly than others:

- Blonde ale (Strawberry blonde, &c.)
- Hefeweissen/wheat ale
- Berliner Weisse (traditionally with a shot of woodruff or raspberry syrup; blueberry, apricot, peach (Dogfish Head Festina Peche is a great example))
- Lambic (Framboise (raspberry), Kriek (cherry), Cassis (currant), Pomme (apple))

But if you look at something like [RateBeer's Fruit Beer ratings list](http://www.ratebeer.com/beerstyles/fruit-beer/40/), you'll see entries for almost every style category.